# Sequelize order by join table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a `Duel` type, each `Duel` has a list of players.
This is my query and relationship:

```
const duel = Duel.findByPk(id, {
    include: duelRelations,
  });


const duelRelations = [{
  model: User,
  as: 'players',
  include: [{
    model: DuelPokemon,
    required: false,
    as: 'duelPokemons',
  }],
}, {
  model: DuelActionLog,
  required: false,
  as: 'logs',
}];
```

relationship:

```
// Each duel has many users
Duel.hasMany(User, {
  foreignKey: 'duel_id',
  as: 'players',
});
```

I want to get the `players` array sorted by the `createdAt` field of the `duel_players` table.
I have tried different combinations of `order` value, but nothing worked. No idea how to define it.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`sequelize.col()`](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#static-method-col) to specify the column from the joined table that you want to sort by in the `order` property of the `findByPk` options. Each order by entry is an array with two parts (the column, then the order) an you can pass in multiple entries to sort by multiple columns.

I moved the `duelRelations` into the options to make it easier to read. In your example you are aliasing `User` as `players` and `DuelPokemon` as `duelPokemons`. Note that you will have needed to define these associations for each `Model`. Your question mentions `duel_players` which doesn't exist in your example, but I think you meant to say `players.createdAt`.

```js
const duel = Duel.findByPk(id, {
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'players',
      include: { // can be an object to include single table
        model: DuelPokemon,
        required: false,
        as: 'duelPokemons',
      },
    },
    {
      model: DuelActionLog,
      required: false,
      as: 'logs',
    },
  ],
  order: [[sequelize.col('players.createdAt'), 'DESC']],
});
```

Comment: It's not really working: `Unknown column 'duelRelations.createdAt`

Comment: @TheUnreal sorry i misread the question, the answer is updated. I think you need to use `players.createdAt` but it's hard to tell - your question mentions `duel_players`?